# Defining subsets of data frame using loop

Tags: r

I have the problem following: Let say, I have data frame which contains three columns e.g.

```
X=data.frame(rnorm(100),rexp(100),runif(100))
```

Now I want to define data.frames Q1,Q2 and Q3 as

```
Q1=X[,1][2:100], 

Q2=X[,2][2:100] and 

Q3=X[,3][2:100]
```

by using loop. Do you have any idea/hints how can I do it ?

Comment: Do you mean `lapply(X, function(x) data.frame(a = x[2:100]))` ?

Comment: But how can I define three new variables ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the code below is what you want

```
list2env(setNames(X[-1,],paste0("Q",seq_along(X))),envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

then you will see `Q1`, `Q2` and `Q3` in your global environment.

Comment: Exactly what I want ;))

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting your data frame on every column which will create a list with 3 data frames, each consisting of one column of `X`. You can then set the names of the list, i.e.

```
setNames(split.default(X, names(X)), paste0('Q', seq(ncol(X))))
```

It is better to keep them in the list but if you want to have them in your global environment then you can do,

```
list2env(setNames(split.default(X, names(X)), paste0('Q', seq(ncol(X)))), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

The above will create three data frames named `Q1`, `Q2`and `Q3` since the list we passed it is named with those names